# Connection to spin 1/2 electron system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

In another Physics stack exchange thread here, [Spin matrix for various spacetime fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119381/spin-matrix-for-various-spacetime-fields[/url])  I obtained the generator of rotations of the SO(2) rotation group for an infinitesimal rotation of 2D vectors.  I then tried to relate this to the spin-1/2 electron system, but it appears vectors representing states for that system transform under the Pauli matrices instead.  I believe this is because those sets of matrices, when scaled properly, yield the correct eigenvalues for the operators.

However, I also noticed that $$D(\omega) = \text{Id} + \omega \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0 \end{pmatrix} = \text{Id} + i \omega \begin{pmatrix} 0&-i \\i&0 \end{pmatrix},$$ so I seemed to have made contact with one of the Pauli matrices, (i.e the scaled form of which the spin states do transform).  It looks like the above is the infinitesimal version of $\exp(i\omega \hat n \cdot \sigma)$ with $$\hat n \cdot \sigma = \sigma_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&-i \\ i&0 \end{pmatrix}$$ which seems to mean $\hat n = (0,1,0)$. In particular, c.f Sakurai P.159, eqn (3.2.3), he says that the physical spin 1/2 electron system does transform under the operator $D(\phi) = \exp(-iS_z\phi/\hbar)$ which is analogous to what I have above with the replacements $\phi \rightarrow \omega$ and $ S_z/\hbar \rightarrow \hat n \cdot \sigma$.

So is there really a connection to the matrix I derived and the spin 1/2 electron system? I do actually think not, since the matrix I derived in that other thread came from analyzing the rotation of vectors in space-time but the spin states live in another space. On the other hand, the analysis above makes me think otherwise at the same time.

Many thanks for clarification!

Comment: The Pauli matrices are the generators of the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ Lie algebra, which coincides with the Spin Lie algebra since the spin group covers the rotation group, so it is not surprising (in fact, expected) that their infinitesimal versions around the identity be the same.

Comment: Hi ACuriousMind.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'the spin group covers the rotation group'? Thanks very much.

Comment: It is a [covering space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_cover_%28topology%29) with fiber dimensionality $2$, to be exact. It is known (with a bit of footing in group theory and the like) that the Lie algebras of any Lie groups that are covers of each other coincide. And since the infinitesimal form of a transformation is just $1 + g$, where $g$ is a Lie-algebra element, you have just "rediscovered" that the Spin group and the rotation group have the same Lie algebra

Comment: Ah, is it related to the isomorphism $SO(3)$ and the factor group $SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2$? Okay, so if I then exponentiate my result, is it correct to say that I will obtain an operator that will transform the spin 1/2 states? (at least by doing so, as I said in the OP, I recover the form of one of the operators Sakurai mentions in his book).

Comment: Jup, since the Pauli matrices are the fundamental representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, exponentiating them will yield an element of the fundamental rep of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, which is the spin-1/2 rep (i.e. the exponentiated forms act naturally on spin-1/2 states, indeed)

Comment: Thank you. You said that the spin group is a cover for the rotation group. Is the isomorphism between $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ more general then to cover rotation groups of different dimension? Also, I was wondering if there is a particular reason why this choice of Pauli matrix showed up here after rearranging the $SO(2)$ generator. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Ok, enough commenting, I'm writing an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not surprising that you found one of the Pauli matrices as the generator of your rotation. Let us see how it can be seen algebraically that it is to be expected:

Observe that 2D rotations embed naturally into 2D unitary matrices, as $\mathrm{SO}(2) \subset \mathrm{SU}(2)$, corresponding to the subgroup of real matrices. Now, as we know, the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is generated by the Pauli matrices, and Lie subgroups must be generated by Lie subalgebras. The question is - which Lie subalgebra is generating the $\mathrm{SO}(2)$?

Well, the one generating the real matrices of course! If you examine<sup>1</sup> the Pauli matrices, you will see that only the one you found by directly linearizing a 2D rotation is giving real instead of complex matrices when exponentiated. Now, how can we be sure that's it? Because 2D rotations are isomorphic to the $\mathrm{U}(1)$, the one-dimensional Lie group, and so we expect only one generator.

---

<sup>1</sup> Observe that $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi (\hat n \cdot \vec \sigma)} = \boldsymbol{1}\mathrm{cos}(\phi) + \mathrm{i}(\hat n \cdot \vec \sigma)\mathrm{sin}(\phi) $. Plugging in the explicit form of the Pauli matrices, we find that the summand from $n_y\sigma_y$ is real (since $\mathrm{i}\sigma_y$ is real), while the others are complex.

Comment: Many thanks! The only part I did not understand is this sentence here:  'If you examine the Pauli matrices, you will see that only the one you found by directly linearizing a 2D rotation is giving real instead of complex matrices when exponentiated'. Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: @CAF: Added a footnote

Comment: Great, thanks.  My last question would be when we exponentiate, the result is $D(\omega) = \exp(i\omega S_y/\hbar)$, since $S_i \rightarrow \hbar \sigma_i/2$, so by exponentiating we seem to have obtained an operator that encodes a rotation of a spin 1/2 state by angle $\omega$ around the y-axis. Is this a correct interpretation?  I guess if this was correct, a follow-up question would be why physically are we obtaining such a result from exponentiation?

Comment: @CAF: Uhh...I believe that is not a correct interpretation, since the operator $D(\omega)$ we obtained *does not* act upon a representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, but on a representation of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$. It's just because $\mathrm{SO}(2)\subset \mathrm{SU}(2)$ that they look the same.

Comment: Ok, but then if $D(\omega)$ acts on a representation of $SO(2)$ then why would it transform the spin 1/2 states?

Comment: @CAF: *It doesn't*. It just looks like the spin-1/2 operator in $y$ direction, it is *not* that operator. The spin operator lives on a rep of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, while $D(\omega)$ does not. My comment on your question earlier was not entirely correct in that respect.

Comment: Ah okay, it has all come together.  Just a final (unrelated) question: when we speak of spin operators $S_i$, the index $i$ always seems to run from 1 to 3 in all physical systems (e.g for the spin 1/2 system living in a 2D Hilbert space, we still consider three spin components).  Why is this?  Many thanks again for your time and insights. + 1 and accepted.

Comment: Because you seem to have been only exposed to non-relativistic spin, which arises from representations of the generators of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, which are precisely the three Pauli matrices (think of it this way: how else could you measure angular momentum if not along the three cardinal axes?). If you consider spin in QFT, it arises from reps of the (proper orthochronous) Lorentz group, and you have more than these generators (and lose the easy interpretation of "spin" along the three space axes).

Comment: I see.  I understand that a 3x3 rotation matrix can be represented as an element of $SO(3)$ and that spin obeys the same commutation relations as angular momentum (which for rotations in three dimensions, has reps of $SO(3)$ as these matrices which act on the kets in the space).  But even for the spin 1/2 electron system, which is a 2D Hilbert space, we still permit these three linearly independent rotations.  Why is that?

Comment: @CAF: The Hilbert space is 2D as a complex space, and the "three" in "three linearly independent" rotations is counted on the Lie algebra as a real space. If you can distill your slight confusions about spin and related stuff into a new question, that would probably be more appropriate than discussing it here.